# Facebook Marketing to Instagram, Documentation error (Ad Creative)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-marketing-api

**Facebook documentation error**

Currently this topic is not updated: [Ad Creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ad_creative)

When you are using Facebook Marketing to create a new creative to Instagram, Facebook recommends use these classes:

- use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeLinkData;
- use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeLinkDataFields;
- use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeObjectStorySpec;
- use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields;

For a correct classes go to the next link: [Ad Creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative)

Comment: This is not really a question that I can see. Usually the best way to post helpful information, is to come up with some kind of related question, and then answer your own question with the helpful information.

Comment: If the documentation is not up-to-date (or otherwise wrong), you should file a documentation bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Ready  was reported in facebook bugs, thanks for the recommendation.